# Why does a Linux autostarted java program not have access to the network?

Tags: java, linux, systemd

I am trying to start up a Java program automatically when Arch Linux boots. I have created a systemd service file which points to a shell file that starts the Java program. All of this works and the Java program starts on boot. The problem is that the Java program, which works properly when manually started by a logged in user, is no longer able to access the network. Since the program is started as a service there is no associated user. Is this the problem?
Thanks for your assistance!